# MTP usb driver failed

Tags: usb, samsung-kies, mtp

I upgraded my Samsung Galaxy Ace 2 GT-i8160. Everything went smoothly during the upgrade, but when it's almost finished, it got disconnected from the PC for no reason. When it reconnected again, it says that the MTP USB driver failed.

I can't connect my USB cable to the PC no matter which port I insert it in. Now my phone won't open.

Answer (score 0):

I had tried tons of proposed solution and it seem doesn't work for my Samsung Note 3. However i finally solve without installing/uninstalling anything.

Problem Solved as following;

1) Reboot phone to Recovery Mode.

2) Wipe Cache Partition.

3) Restart phone and connect to PC.

Bum!!! Window successfully installed your MTP driver.